# Working with AWK regex

Tags: regex, parsing, awk

I have a file in which have values in following format-

```
20/01/2012 01:14:27;UP;UserID;User=bob email=abc@sample.com
```

I want to pick each value from this file (not labels). By saying label, i mean to say that for string `email=abc@sample.com`, i only want to pick `abc@sample.com` and for sting `User=bob`, i only want to pic `bob`. All the Space separated values are easy to pick but i am unable to pick the values separated by Semi colon. Below is the command i am using in `awk`-

```
awk '{print "1=",$1} /;/{print "2=",$2,"3=",$3}' sample_file
```

In `$2`, i am getting the complete string till `bob` and rest of the string is assigned to `$3`. Although i can work with `substr` provided with `awk` but i want to be on safe side, string length may vary.
Can somebody tell me how to design such `regex` to parse my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set multiple delimiters using `awk -F`:

```
awk -F "[ \t;=]+" '{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8 }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
value1 value2 value3 value4 label1 value5 label2 value6
```

**EDIT:**

You can remove anything before the equal signs using `sub (/[^=]*=/,"", $i)`. This will allow you to just print the 'values':

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[ \t;]+"; OFS=" " } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sub (/[^=]*=/,"", $i); line = (line ? line OFS : "") $i } print line; line = "" }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
20/01/2012 01:14:27 UP UserID bob abc@sample.com
```

Comment: what if i want to ignore `label1` and `label2`. since i am only interested in `value1...x`

Comment: actually i provided the format of file. U can assume values to any number or sting. These values are random. The point which is noticeable, is that in file some values are separated by SPACE, some are separated by SEMI COLON and rest of them has some label like name=steve. So for these labels i am only concern about the value, which is steve here.

Comment: @RaviJoshi: I'm not exactly sure what you are meaning, does this help? Perhaps you could add some more sample data?

Comment: I edited my question. Hope this will help to better understand it. Let me know if any doubt is there?

Comment: @RaviJoshi: See the edit, I hope it helps. Also, how should we handle values containing an equal sign?

Comment: @RaviJoshi: No problem, I thought I should make the matching of the equal sign non-greedy: `sub (/[^=]*=/,"", $i)`.  This will match anything not an equal sign any number of times, followed by an equal sign, and remove it. This replaces the 'greedy' matching: `sub (/^.*=/,"", $i)`.